# How to get all currently spawned vehicles in sumo through traci

Tags: c++, veins, sumo

I have a question about sumo/traci.

In python there exist functions for retrieving values from sumo:
[sumo documentation](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/Vehicle_Value_Retrieval.html#Extended_retrieval_messages)

How do I do that in C++,
specifically i need a list of all vehicles which are currently in the simulation.

Thank You

Comment: [libsumo::Vehicle Class Reference](https://sumo.dlr.de/daily/doxygen/de/d9a/classlibsumo_1_1_vehicle.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Veins 5.0, you can find a list of all implemented methods for interacting with SUMO in https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h

Specifically, though, the list of all currently-simulated vehicles can most reliably be obtained by calling `TraCIScenarioManager::getManagedHosts` (see https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h#L106 )

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Veins, have a look here: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/C++TraCIAPI.html which gives an explanation how to build a client application using the C++ API. The methods you can use are documented here:
https://sumo.dlr.de/daily/doxygen/d8/d1c/class_tra_c_i_a_p_i.html

You might want to use getIDList() from the VehicleScope.